# Excel 2010 Pivot Table corrupting data

Tags: excel, pivot

I have an excel pivot table that when refreshed is corrupting data.  It basically loses the one value and replaces it with another.

So the datasheet has the value of "Kramerville" in the prosperator column and "Rustenburg" but the pivot table has changed it so there is no "Kramerville" but "Rustenburg" and "Rustenburg2".

Anyone know why it would behave like this?

Thanks

Comment: Two possibilities. 1. It is possible that you typed over Kramerville and accidentally renamed it to Rustenburg. The way PivotTables work is that it lets you rename things locally on a PivotTable and it remembers that. 2. If the data warehouse is truncated and rebuilt daily even the dimensions it is possible that surrogate key 99 meant Kramerville yesterday but means Rustenburg today.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those were the issue.  I did consider those and check them- but neither was the case.  It just appears to have been pure data file corruption

Answer (score 0):

I did not find why it had happened but it seems to have been a corrupted file.  My suggestion for anyone having the same issue- copy your data into a new file and recreate the pivot, that cleared the issue for me.  I used exactly the same VBA code in the new file and it works perfectly,  If I discover why the data corrupted I will update so people know how to avoid the same issue