# Corrupted pivot table based on SSAS cube

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, tabular

I have an issue with a pivot table in Excel connected to a SSAS tabular model cube. For unknown reasons pivot tables based on this cube get corrupted sometimes. The displayed column and row labels don't match the by the user selected labels. Every time I refresh the pivot table the label’s gets mixed up even more. When I copy the pivot table into a new Excel-file the issue is solved. But I can't find the cause of the pivot table getting corrupted.

Has anybody encountered the same problem?

Comment: What version of Excel? If Excel 2013 then make sure you have the latest updates installed: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/office-2013-365-update?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961532/excel-2010-pivot-table-corrupting-data

Comment: Excel 2013 with the latest updates. I did found an other tread with a similar problem.

Comment: see my comment I added to that other thread. Could that explain your problem?

Comment: The underlying datasource (sql-server database) for the tabular model is truncated and rebuilt every day. Processing option for the tabular model is full. If I rebuilt the same pivot table in a new Excel-file or copy the pivot table from the corrupted Excel-file to a new Excel-file, the pivot table works fine. That's why I don't think it's a design mistake in the tabular model, but a problem within the Excel-file.